# How to measure processes in Total Blocking Time in Google PageSpeed?

Tags: google, performance, page-speed

I am trying to measure specific TBT as outlined in [Google's documentation](https://web.dev/tbt/)

> The Total Blocking Time (TBT) metric measures the total amount of time between First Contentful Paint (FCP) and Time to Interactive (TTI) where the main thread was blocked for long enough to prevent input responsiveness.

Where 'long enough' is more than 50ms. It appears that none of the tools (GPSI, lighthouse, webpagetest) provide specific ways to find all processes greater than 50ms AFTER FCP and before TTI. Or, at least that I can see. Maybe I am missing something one of these tools provide.

Any thoughts on how to find these specific tasks?